# Angular: using async pipe by custom setting the variable value

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, pipe

I have parent component A and a lot (20+) child components, all extending A and being located inside `<ng-content></ng-content>`. In component A I'm setting value of `showContent` variable in multiple places.

The problem is that I'm using `*ngIf="showContent"` in all child components. Because the child components' views are not updated when the value in A is changed I can either:

A) use Output + EventEmitter but I would not like to have

```
onValueChange(val: boolean) {
  this.showContent = val;
}
```

in every child component (20+ times same code);

B) use async pipe. The problem is that I'm setting value in GET/POST subscriptions

```
this.httpDataHandler.get<...>(...).subscribe(response => {
    // lots of stuff
    showContent = true;
});
```

Is there any way to use async pipe and remove redundant code from all children?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you could use a `BehaviorSubject` here :

```
showContent = new BehaviorSubject(false)
...
this.httpDataHandler.get<...>(...).subscribe(response => {
  // lots of stuff
  showContent.next(true);
});
...
*ngIf="showContent | async"
```

or use the `ChangeDetectorRef`

```
constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
... 
this.httpDataHandler.get<...>(...).subscribe(response => {
  // lots of stuff
  showContent = true;
  this.cdr.markForCheck();
});
...
*ngIf="showContent"
```

In general when you have these kinds of problems, you are trying to extract data from your observables too soon. You may have a better solution with some refactoring where you would avoid the subscription. But without the full code its hard to tell how...